# android, how can I add keyboard permission to manifest?

Tags: android, keyboard, touch, manifest

I have finished my first application and published in android marketplace (https://market.android.com/details?id=Mobilesoft.asia.numbers&feature=search_result)

My problem is, in upload page is written:
**This apk requests 1 features that will be used for Android Market filtering:** 
android.hardware.touchscreen

while this game is designed for all touchscreen and non-touch devices. If device doesn't support touch, the player can play with keyboard, joystick or navigation keys. How can I say this application is able to support non-touch devices?

Comment: Are there any Android devices which can access the market and do not have touchscreens?

Comment: in the permissions tab it says THIS APPLICATION REQUIRES NO SPECIAL PERMISSIONS TO RUN.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know, does my application able to be downloaded on none touchscreen devices as well as touch devices?

Comment: I got a similar message when I uploaded an application. IIRC, after playing around with the manifest to try to eliminate it, I gave up and just uploaded it and didn't have any problem. You can upload and test to see if it downloads ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue with my Android app. I think Google adds the `android.hardware.touchscreen` filter because you're using some feature in your code that requires a touchscreen.

What happens when the `android.hardware.touchscreen` filter is applied is that your app no longer shows up when someone has a device that does not support a touchscreen. You won't be able to say that your application supports non touch screen devices until you remove whatever part of your code that has required the filter.